# SAML Assumed-Role user not authorized to perform actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I'm using OKTA as our Identity Provider which is allowing me to dictate which Roles users can Assume when logging into the Console.

The Goal:
Have a Role that allows a user to log into the console and only manage their Access Keys (List, Create, Update, Delete).

This Policy *should* allow the current user to manage their own keys but I get this error when trying to do anything other than List the access keys

`User: arn:aws:sts::[ACCOUNT-NUMBER]:assumed-role/AccessKeyManagement/[Logged In Username] is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateAccessKey on resource: user [Logged In Username]`

Granted if I change the Resource to be `"*"` it will work but the user can alter other account Access Keys.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Role Trusted Relationships (just in case it's needed)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT-NUMBER]:saml-provider/OKTA"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm at a loss as to what I need to do to allow the "Assumed-Role" of the current user permission to modify the Access keys.

Comment: see if `${aws:userid}` works.

Comment: You may also try to add account number instead of * in resources as  `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/${aws:username}`

Comment: @Asdfg ${aws:userid} didn't work. When i hardcode the user `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/jim` everything works as expected. But when i try to add the dynamic username it fails.

Answer (score 0):

So, an IAM role does not have permanent access key associated with it and you get temporary credentials (access keys, secret key and session token) when you login to the console. 
Now, the "${aws:username}" resolves to IAM user name and it does not apply to IAM role. Thus you can't manage the access key creation of IAM roles and you don't have to.

Comment: Some users still need access keys for their tasks and we want them to be able to manage their own keys. We do want to resolve the IAM username because the IAM Username must be the same as what is configured on the SAML side.

Comment: If your users need access keys, you can use programmatically retrieve it but you might have to write the code depending which SAML provider you're using. You cannot resolve the IAM role with SAML federation to IAM username as those are two different entities. For IAM user, the authentication is taken care by AWS where when you use SAML it happens at your Identity Provider. So when you are using SAML, the username attribute itself is not similar to IAM user name. Using IAM role is the whole point of not to mange IAM users and their long term credentials.

Comment: I see you are using Okta. You might have a look in the article from Okta: https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Integrating-the-Amazon-Web-Services-Command-Line-Interface-Using-Okta